# drl drivers work but passenger does not

Tags: chevrolet, lights, aveo

2007 chevy aveo daytime running light works on drivers side. Turn lights to on and the drivers side goes out and the passenger side comes on. Bright lights work for both at same time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it the DRL runs off of the headlight? (i.e.: Some manufacturers run the headlights at reduced power to make them a DRL.)

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly a bad ground (floating), or more likely a bad DRL module.

Does the DRL indicator come on in the instrument cluster at the proper time?  I can be fairly certain the problem is NOT the DRL relay, the headlight switch, any fuse, or bulbs.

Electrical Diagram below:

[image: 2007 Aveo Headlight Wiring and DRL module]